# Bigquery - Window function - Sum over last 3 months

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am looking to sum a column over the last 3 months using WINDOW function.

An example of what my data structure is as follows

Date       Customer_id Amount

01-01-2020 A           100.0

01-02-2020 A           100.0

01-03-2020 A           100.0

01-04-2020 A           100.0
....

My current approach is to create a WINDOW function as follows:

```
WINDOW
90d_rolling AS (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 89 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

This proxies 3 months as 90 days - but I was wondering if it is possible to sum over last 3 months USING A WINDOW FUNCTION i.e. for the date of 01-04-2020 -> it would sum up till 01-01-2020.

**Note that** I know that a way of doing this is via

```
left join to itself where a.date >= date_sub(b.date, interval 3 month) and a.date <= b.date
```

(but i am just curious if there is a another way)

Comment: Why have you tagged so many random things here? SQL Server, and PostgreSQL? Amazon Redshift and Google BigQuery? These are all competing products. Please tag correctly. I have removed them all apart from [tag:sql].

Comment: I added BigQuery back to tags as it is explicitly claimed in Question Title

Comment: what is your definition of last 3 month? is is last three full months or it is period between given day exact same day but three month ago or something else?

Comment: Last 3 months from the date so for a row with date = "2019-12-01" the window will be back to "2019-09-01"
code: select date_sub("2019-12-01", interval 3 month)

Answer (score 5):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  SUM(amount) OVER(
    PARTITION BY customer_id 
    ORDER BY DATE_DIFF(`date`, '2000-01-01', MONTH)
    RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) AS rolling_3m_ammount
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Note: based sample data in your question and comments - I assume all dates are first day of month!

You can test, play with above using sample/dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' `date`, 'A' customer_id, 1.0 amount UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-02-01', 'A', 2.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-03-01', 'A', 3.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-04-01', 'A', 4.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-05-01', 'A', 5.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-07-01', 'A', 6.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-09-01', 'A', 7.0 
)
SELECT *, 
  SUM(amount) OVER(
    PARTITION BY customer_id 
    ORDER BY DATE_DIFF(`date`, '2000-01-01', MONTH)
    RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) AS rolling_3m_ammount
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY `date`
```

with output

```
Row date        customer_id amount  rolling_3m_ammount   
1   2020-01-01  A           1.0     null     
2   2020-02-01  A           2.0     1.0  
3   2020-03-01  A           3.0     3.0  
4   2020-04-01  A           4.0     6.0  
5   2020-05-01  A           5.0     9.0  
6   2020-07-01  A           6.0     9.0  
7   2020-09-01  A           7.0     6.0
```